# Unwanted white space between rows when bootstrap enabled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was creating a table and suddenly this white space showed up between rows. I tried some things but couldn't get it to go away.

Later realised that it happened only when bootstrap was enabled
When I remove bootstrap css file it gets fixed.

Here is without bootstrap

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url(https://ambrosia-servers.com/adminactivity/images/background.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:     cover;
 top: 0px;
 }

.table th h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #C6B642;
    padding: 5px;
}

.table td {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    padding: 10px;
}

.table {
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /*padding: 0 0 8em 0;*/
}

.table td,
.table th {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #252424;
}

.table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: black 0px solid;
}

.table th {
    background-color: #2B2B1B;
}

.table td:first-child {
 background-color: #2b2b1b;
    color: #C6B642;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.table tr:hover {
    background-color: #464A52;
}

.table td:hover {
    background-color: #C6B642;
    color: #403E10;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-property: all;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .table td:nth-child(4),
    .table th:nth-child(4) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><h1>Sites</h1></th>
   <th><h1>Views</h1></th>
   <th><h1>Clicks</h1></th>
   <th><h1>Average</h1></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Google</td>
   <td>9518</td>
   <td>6369</td>
   <td>01:32:50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Twitter</td>
   <td>7326</td>
   <td>10437</td>
   <td>00:51:22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Amazon</td>
   <td>4162</td>
   <td>5327</td>
   <td>00:24:34</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>LinkedIn</td>
   <td>3654</td>
   <td>2961</td>
   <td>00:12:10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>CodePen</td>
   <td>2002</td>
   <td>4135</td>
   <td>00:46:19</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>GitHub</td>
   <td>4623</td>
   <td>3486</td>
   <td>00:31:52</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Bootstrap enabled

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url(https://ambrosia-servers.com/adminactivity/images/background.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:     cover;
 top: 0px;
 }

.table th h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #C6B642;
    padding: 5px;
}

.table td {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    padding: 10px;
}

.table {
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /*padding: 0 0 8em 0;*/
}

.table td,
.table th {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #252424;
}

.table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: black 0px solid;
}

.table th {
    background-color: #2B2B1B;
}

.table td:first-child {
 background-color: #2b2b1b;
    color: #C6B642;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.table tr:hover {
    background-color: #464A52;
}

.table td:hover {
    background-color: #C6B642;
    color: #403E10;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-property: all;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .table td:nth-child(4),
    .table th:nth-child(4) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><h1>Sites</h1></th>
   <th><h1>Views</h1></th>
   <th><h1>Clicks</h1></th>
   <th><h1>Average</h1></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Google</td>
   <td>9518</td>
   <td>6369</td>
   <td>01:32:50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Twitter</td>
   <td>7326</td>
   <td>10437</td>
   <td>00:51:22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Amazon</td>
   <td>4162</td>
   <td>5327</td>
   <td>00:24:34</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>LinkedIn</td>
   <td>3654</td>
   <td>2961</td>
   <td>00:12:10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>CodePen</td>
   <td>2002</td>
   <td>4135</td>
   <td>00:46:19</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>GitHub</td>
   <td>4623</td>
   <td>3486</td>
   <td>00:31:52</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like Bootstrap adds a border to the table cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your css - you already have the classes set. you just need to add the border-top to that section.

```
.table td, .table th { 
    border: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: with that still the border remains, `border` only solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Of course, it'll only works if your CSS is executed after the Bootstrap import. Otherwise, you'll need a `border-top: none !important` to force the override.

Comment: Yes it does. But are you calling your custom CSS before or after Bootstrap? If it's before, then Bootstrap's CSS will take precedence. Pull in this CSS after your Bootstrap import.